# generate constructor with inhereted fields

Tags: java, intellij-idea

IntelliJ IDEA generates constructors (Alt + Insert) only with the local fields, but not with the fields inherited from superclass.

This sounds like a bug to me. Or is it possible somehow?

**EDITED:**

[image: constructor generator]

Comment: **Default** constructor of the parent class is called **automatically**. If you neeed constructor with a specific signature then  `super(.....)` should be called as the 1st statement of a constructor.

Comment: I'm talking about IntelliJ IDEA feature, which generates constructors for selected fields. The problem is that this feature only shows local fields, not the inherited ones.

Comment: Are you saying that you do not see super-class fields being initiated at **run-time** or just in **the body** of the sub-class constructor?

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA does not provide me superclass fields to select in the list of fields. The question is purely about IDEA functionality.

Comment: It's a responsibility of a super class to initialize its variables.  You should not do it **directly** in a sub-class constructor at all.  You need to call the proper version of the super-class constructor to do it, unless the default one already does it.

Comment: In my case superclass is just a JPA class with set of commonly used fields. Anyway, taking your approach would be also fine in case IDEA could generate super(....) call to superclass for me with selected fields. Which is also not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The superclass fields are not displayed in the list because they are meant to be initialized by the superclass constructor; this behavior is by design and not a bug.

When you invoke the "Generate constructor" action, it offers you to select the superclass constructor to call. The parameters of the generated constructor will be a combination of the parameters of the selected superclass constructor and the list of fields in the current class that you have selected in the dialog.

Comment: Awesome! It really generates super(...) call automatically. Didn't know that. Thank you!